# cannot retrieve data from database with mysqli in php

Tags: php, database, mysqli, web

I am having some trouble figuring out what exactly is wrong with my code I cannot seem to retrieve data from my database.

I get absolutely no errors on php checker, it worked previously before when testing then I extended the code to have a better search pattern and now half way through coding all of a sudden it stops working and I cannot figure out the problem.

I know the connection to my database works as I am using it for another part of my website.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
            include("search/dbconnect.php");
            $count;
            $searchtext= $_POST['search-box'];
            $searchbit=explode(" ", $_POST['search-box']);
            $searchsound= metaphone($_POST['search-box']);
            $sqlName="SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE '%".$_POST['search-box']."%'";
            $sqltext="SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE '%".$_POST['search-box']."%' OR PGKeywords LIKE '%".$_POST['search-box']."%' ";
            $sqlsound="SELECT metaphonetext.*, SearchPG.* FROM metaphonetext JOIN SearchPG ON metaphonetext.PGID=SearchPG.PGID WHERE metaphonetext.NameSound LIKE '%".$searchsound."%'";
            $qryname=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sqlName);
            $qrytext=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sqltext);
            $qrysound=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sqlsound);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($qryname)>0){
                $rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryname);
                do{
                    ?>
                    <div class="row resultcontent">
                        <a href="<?php echo $rs['PGUrl'];?>">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                <img src="<?php echo $rs['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                <div class="contshading">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                <h1><?php echo $rs['PGName'];?></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $count++;
                } while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryname));
            } elseif(mysqli_num_rows($qrytext)>0){
                foreach($searchbit as $value){
                    $temp = $value;
                    $sqltext="SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE '%".$temp."%' OR PGKeyword LIKE '%".$temp."%' ";
                    $qrytext=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sqltext);
                    $rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrytext);
                    do{
                    ?>
                        <div class="row resultcontent">
                        <a href="<?php echo $rs['PGUrl'];?>">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                <img src="<?php echo $rs['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                <div class="contshading">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                <h1><?php echo $rs['PGName'];?></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $count++;
                } while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrytext));
                }
            } elseif(mysqli_num_rows($qrysound)>0){
                $rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrysound);
                do{
                    ?>
                    <div class="row resultcontent">
                        <a href="<?php echo $rs['PGUrl'];?>">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                <img src="<?php echo $rs['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                <div class="contshading">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                <h1><?php echo $rs['PGName'];?></h1>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    $count++;
                } while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrysound)); 
            }else{
                foreach($searchbit as $value){
                    $temp = metaphone($value);
                    $sqlsound="SELECT metaphonetext.*, SearchPG.* FROM metaphonetext JOIN PGName ON metaphonetext.PGID=SearchPG.PGID WHERE metaphonetext.NameSound LIKE '%".$temp."%'";
                    $sqlsoundkey="SELECT metaphonetext.*, SearchPG.* FROM metaphonetext JOIN PGKeywords ON metaphonetext.PGID=SearchPG.PGID WHERE metaphonetext.KeywordSound LIKE '%".$temp."%'";
                    $qrysound=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sqlsound);
                    $qrysoundkey=mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sqlsoundkey);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($qrysound)>0){
                        $rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrysound);
                        do{
                        ?>
                            <div class="row resultcontent">
                                <a href="<?php echo $rs['PGUrl'];?>">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $rs['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                        <div class="contshading">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                        <h1><?php echo $rs['PGName'];?></h1>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        } while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrysound));
                    }else if(mysqli_num_rows($qrysoundkey)>0){
                        $rskey=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrysoundkey);
                        do{
                        ?>
                            <div class="row resultcontent">
                                <a href="<?php echo $rskey['PGUrl'];?>">
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 searchRsltCont">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $rskey['PGImgUrl'];?>" class="searchRsltimg" alt="search result image" />
                                        <div class="contshading">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 searchRslttxt">
                                        <h1><?php echo $rskey['PGName'];?></h1>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        } while($rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrysoundkey));
                    }else if(mysqli_num_rows($qrysound)<=0 && mysqli_num_rows($qrysoundkey)<=0){
                        ?>
                        <p>no results found</p>
                        <?php
                    }else{
                        ?>
                            <p>no more results found</p>
                        <?php
                    }
                }


            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Define "it stops working".  What is the specific problem?  When you debug this, where/how exactly does it fail?  Also note that your code has a huge SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: just a side-note, always initialize all variables in the program, `$count = 0`

Comment: Don't ever put user data directly into MySQL queries. This is asking for trouble: `$sqlName="SELECT * FROM SearchPG WHERE PGName LIKE '%".$_POST['search-box']."%'";`. Learn how to do prepared queries instead.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming your queries could never fail. never EVER assume success when dealing with external resources (e.g. databases). always check for failure.

Comment: @david it just does not retrieve the data from the database and I thought that only mattered when inputting data to a database but ill fix that now will a simple mysqli_real_escape_String in the qrys work

Comment: @squeamishossifrage ok have you got any good links on where i could learn to fix this problem

Comment: @MarcB Ill fix that now and the fail state is nested within the else statement also this search engine is not yet finished there is a lot to be improved upon including fail state but I must figure out what I broke in the process before continuing haha.

Comment: your fail state checking is anything but. checking for rows returned is NOT failure checking. an empty result set is still a perfectly valid result set. but all of those query() calls return boolean FALSE on failure, and you need to check for THAT.

Comment: @MarcB oh ok thanks ill make sure to fix that, I thought it would return a 0 on failure.

Comment: num_rows = 0 is a successful query that returned NO rows. e.g. `select 1=0`.. num_rows = false is a failed query.

Comment: @MarcB thanks I took your advice and it appears the qrys are failing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for pointing out the flaws in my code if I had not posted here I would not have known any of this until my database was attacked, I am working on fixing them now. I figured out my problem was not the code though it was more to do with my lack of knowledge, you see after testing I moved my dbconnection parameters to an ini file and stored them outside of my root folder to keep it safe, there for the dbconnection variable then became a local variable and basically unusable outside of the folder the variable was stored in. The solution was simple I just moved my search engine to the same folder.